# Tabula directory to read pdf

Tags: python, pandas, tabula

How can I read directory pdf,
my directory is incorrect and I do not understand why it is so.

Sorry I am new to coding. and I importing the directory in wring manner ?

Your help would be much appreciated !

My apologies for the dumb question.

```
from tabula.io import read_pdf


df = read_pdf(
    "C:/..../sec_annex_2_b_determination_of_corrosion_rate/test_pdf.pdf",
    pages="all")
```

```
    raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: .............../test_pdf.pdf'
```

Comment: How do you run the code? The pdf is in the same directory of the py file?

Comment: @BleakHeart its in the same folder and i also tried forcing the directory " "C:/..../sec_annex_2_b_determination_of_corrosion_rate/test_pdf.pdf" but it does not recognize the directory.

Comment: Try prepending `r` to your path, to make it raw string `r"C:\path\file.pdf"`

Comment: @crayxt unfortunately no luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requires Java integration within IDE

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem it was a guess for me so I was trying many ways doing this boring task of change, add and removing parts of the path even with different slashes and also main anaconda directory.

So basically it was easier, my real route was

```
C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\Estudiando PYTHON\pdfs\informexlsx.pdf
```

So what I had to put was just

```
..\Estudiando PYTHON\pdfs\informexls.pdf
```

so definitive lines are:

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("..\Estudiando PYTHON\pdfs\informexls.pdf")
df
```

I suggest you for purpose of test is better add , `pages="all"` after the path separated by comma and then close the parenthesis.

Also activate Javascript where it says **NOT TRUST**

Comment: Also activate Javascript where it says NOT TRUST